# Getting GetId() to work on a LinkedList()

Tags: android, sqlite, linked-list

Further to my question "Extracting multiple data items from LinkedList() element" which now works fine on the demo "Book" app thanks to quocnhat7, now I'm stuck on the onItemClick where the method getId() method causes "error: cannot find symbol method getId()" on building the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    JCGSQLiteHelper db = new JCGSQLiteHelper(this);
    List list;
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db.createBook(new Book("The waves", "Virginia Woolf"));
        db.createBook(new Book("Mrs Dalloway", "Virginia Woolf"));
        db.createBook(new Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy"));

        // get all books
        List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();
        List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            listTitle.add(i, list.get(i).getTitle());
                    }

        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // start BookActivity with extras the book id
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BookActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("book", list.get(arg2).getId());
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. `list` is defined as non-generic `List`, thus it's `get` method returns an Object, and not `Book`, and `Object` doesn't have a method `getId`.
2. `List<Book> list = db.getAllBooks();` hides the member `List list`, and so there is no assignment to the member `list`.

To fix it, you should do 2 things:

1. Change `list` definition:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
       JCGSQLiteHelper db = new JCGSQLiteHelper(this);
       List<Book> list;
       //  ^^^^^^
   ```
2. Assign to the member, not to a local variable:

   ```
   // get all Books
   list = db.getAllBooks();
   ```

Comment: Genius! Thank you :o) I was staring at that... inspiration eluded me.